# Override WordPress New User registration welcome email

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create a `php` file in my plugins directory called `welcome_email_override.php`

Code:

```
<?php

if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {

 function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plantext_pass = '') {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

        $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
        $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );

        $message  = sprintf( __('New user registration on %s:'), get_option('blogname') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('E-mail: %s'), $user_email ) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(
            get_option('admin_email'),
            sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname') ),
            $message
        );

        if ( empty( $plaintext_pass ) )
            return;

        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('Adios!');

        wp_mail(
            $user_email,
            'Welcome to Premium Stock Music' ),
            $message
        );
 }

}


?>
```

But for some reason my plugin is not kicking in and the WP is using the old new user welcome email.

Comment: What is loading this? You can't just put a basic PHP file in the plugins directory. It needs to have the proper plugin header defined. So if this is exactly what you have, its not being loaded by the system.

Comment: Also, don't suppress errors with @. If you need to do that its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How are you expecting to load the file?  Is it loaded as part of a plugin, or is this supposed to **be** the plugin?  If so, you need a proper plugin header so that you can activate it as a plugin in the plugin panel.

Otherwise, if you are just trying load this function to override the default new user email, then you can add it to your theme's functions.php file.

(Also, you've got a typo in the password argument - "plan..." vs. "plain...")